position streamlit buttons horizontaly next to each others
How to position two buttons in the same line, next to each other.
I had the two following failing attempts.
Attempt 1: The buttons do not get placed side by side
    st.markdown('<div style="display: inline-block;">', unsafe_allow_html=True)    
    st.download_button(
        label="Download data as CSV",
        data="Your DataFrame's CSV data here".encode('utf-8'),
        file_name='filtered_data.csv',
        mime='text/csv',
        key="download_csv"
    )
    if st.button("Reset Metrics", key="reset_metrics"):
        st.experimental_rerun()
    st.markdown('</div>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

Attempt 2: The buttons are side by side, but still very far away from each others
    col = st.columns([0.5, 0.5],gap="small")

    with col[0]:
        st.download_button(
            label="Download data as CSV",
            data=filtered_data.to_csv().encode('utf-8'),
            file_name='filtered_data.csv',
            mime='text/csv',
            key="download_csv"
        )

    with col[1]:
        if st.button("Reset Metrics", key="reset_metrics"):
            st.experimental_rerun()


Does this answer your question? Streamlit how to display buttons in a single line

This would format all the content. I am interested in only potioning the two buttons

The following code is taken as a reference from here, that puts button close to each other and on the same line:
import streamlit as st

st.markdown("""
            <style>
                div[data-testid="column"] {
                    width: fit-content !important;
                    flex: unset;
                }
                div[data-testid="column"] * {
                    width: fit-content !important;
                }
            </style>
            """, unsafe_allow_html=True)

col = st.columns([0.5, 0.5],gap="small")

with col[0]:
    st.button(
            label="Download data as CSV",
           
        )

with col[1]:
    if st.button("Reset Metrics", key="reset_metrics"):
        st.experimental_rerun()

